# setInputText is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'

Tags: typescript

Eu tenho esta variável que me retorna um erro:

> Type '{ setInputText: Dispatch<SetStateAction>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
> Property 'setInputText' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }

Eis o meu código:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Form from './components/Form';

const Props = {
  setInputText: function
}

function App(){
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

  return (
    <main>
      <div>
        <div className="title">
          <h1><span suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable="true">Your name</span> todo list</h1>
        </div>
        <>
        <Form ***setInputText***={setInputText}/>
        </>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: trecho de código]

```
import React from 'react';
import { BsPlusSquareFill } from 'react-icons/bs';

const Form: React.FC = ({ setInputText }: any) => {
  const getInputText = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputText(e.target.value);
  }
  const submitTodoHandler = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("hi")
  }
  return(
    <form>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="inputTodo">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Write here your todo" onChange={getInputText}/>
          < BsPlusSquareFill className="plus-sign" onClick={submitTodoHandler}/>
        </div>
        <select name="todos" id="todos">
          <option value="all">All</option>
          <option value="completed">Completed</option>
          <option value="Uncompleted">Uncompleted</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

export default Form;
```

Como soluciono este problema?

Comment: pode acrescentar o codigo do `Form`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No seu componente `Form` você precisa tipar suas props, como você esta usando o `React.FC` você pode passar os tipos das suas props por generic dessa forma:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BsPlusSquareFill } from 'react-icons/bs';

type IFormProps = {
  setInputText: (value: string) => void
}

const Form: React.FC<IFormProps> = ({ setInputText }) => { ... }
```

Caso você não esteja utilizando o `React.FC` poderia fazer dessa forma também:

```
const Form = ({ setInputText }: IFormProps) => { ... }
```